# "is" vs "was"... relative clause edition?

Tags: relative-clauses

I was doing some exercises when this sentence cropped up:

> I met him in May and it was then that I fell in love with him.

So I'd to rewrite this like this:

> I met him in May, which **was** when I fell in love with him.

It's simple enough to understand; though, the official answer was slightly different:

> I met him in May, which **is** when I fell in love with him.

So was I wrong: is it really necessary that the **was** be **is**? I thought to myself that all of this, of course, took place in the past, so **was** should be correct, shouldn't it? There was also another sentence in yet another example given by the authors themselves:

> He arrived at six, which **was** when the diamonds went missing.

*Is* or *was*, that's the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Both are OK. You can backshift it to "was", or use the present tense "is".